# How to add or associate an rcp plugin project in Sonarqube

Tags: plugins, eclipse-rcp, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have installed Sonarqube plugin in my Eclipse Juno & added SonarQube server 3.7.2. The connection with the server was success. Now I can take the home page of SonarQube from the web browser (localhost:9000/). But when I tried to add my plugin project

Steps:

- Open the project explorer view
- Right click the plugin project >> configure >> Associate with Sonar
- A window with Associate Sonar opened & my plugin project name is shown in the 'Project' tab and in the Sonar project tab one message with "Click to start searching for a Sonar Project" is given.

So is there any additional configuration for associating a Eclipse rcp plugin project in Sonar?

Comment: What's your issue if your project can be selected in the list?